# Jquery working in development mode but not production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a type-ahead drop-down list based on jquery and the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem.  I had to add some files to app/assets/javascript and app/assets/stylesheets.  I've pinpointed the problem in being running the app in dev vs. prod mode.  Does anyone have experience with this and can tell me which settings to change in config/envrionments/production.rb.  I'm having a very difficult time understanding the asset pipeline.

Here's my production config file:

```
Dcms::Application.configure do

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  # config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

   # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
   config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Comment: When JavaScript stops working in Rails from development to production, the problem is most likely related to your assets being precompiled in production.  The first place to look is in your JavaScript console in your browser to see if the error is happening when the page loads or when it starts trying to autocomplete.  If you're doing server-side/ajax autocomplete you should also check your server log to see if the requests are coming in.

Comment: Thanks.  The error happens when my page loads. It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined".  I do not understand that.

Comment: It's really hard to say without being knee deep in your code, but one potential pitfall with compiled assets is the order in which your javascript code appears in the final compressed .js file.  Make sure your js file with all the includes has the heavy library stuff like jquery coming first, and then if you're including whole folders, make sure the code works if the files are read alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

If JS assets are being concatenated, please check if each file end has a ";" . Moreover you might also add a ";" at each JS file start to avoid the previous one to expect what is following to be an argument of a not returned function or somewhat else.

Explanation

File a.js

```
(function() {} )()
```

File b.js

```
(function() {} )()
```

Now concat and what returns the first function sees parenthesis and admit it should have been a function.

Comment: This is a correct answer with respect to autocomplete.  Chiming in late here, but @Joe might have needed to add a few functions - add_fields and remove_fields - and the references I found were lacking the semi-colon